# div with heigth that fills the page

Tags: html, css, height, jsfiddle

Unfortunately, I have always the same problem with heigths of divs.
I want that my div (If the content is minimum) fills the monitor. Otherwhise, if the content exceed the page I use the scrollbar (overflow:scroll) and this part is ok.

My page is composed like this:

```
 <div id="container">
    <div id="header"> ...</div>
            <div id="navigation"> ... </div>
            <div id="content"> ... 
                <div id="testo"></div>
            </div>
```

I would like that the div content match the heigth of the page of the browser.

If you watch this example http://jsfiddle.net/EBnD2/

you can understand what is my problem.

thanks in advance!

Comment: you would be better using some js to calculate the height of the page first

Comment: I don't think this is the way...

Comment: What about `body {margin:0;}` ?

Comment: no, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a script driven solution](http://jsfiddle.net/EBnD2/15/show/):

And the script that does the trick (I've used jQuery for convenience. Feel free to resort to pure javascript, if necessary :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#content").css("height", 
        (
        $(document).outerHeight() 
      - $("#header").outerHeight() 
      - $("#navigation").outerHeight() 
      - $("#footer").outerHeight()
      - parseInt($("#content").css("padding"))) + "px");
    });
```

Here's the updated style definitions:

```
html {
}
body {
    min-width: 1150px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: pink;
    margin: 0px;
}
#container {
    margin: 0 100px;
    background: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#header {
    text-align:center;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    border-left: 1px solid grey;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
}
#header h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
#testo {
    font-family: times, Times New Roman, times-roman, georgia, serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #444;
}
p.sx {
    text-align: left;
}
p.cx {
    text-align: center;
}
p.dx {
    text-align: right;
}
#navigation {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #CC3366;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 90%;
    font-size-adjust: inherit;
}
#navigation ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navigation ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
#navigation li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
#navigation li a:hover {
    background: #993366;
}
#navigation li a.selected {
    background: grey;
}
#content {
    background-color: white;
    border-left: 1px solid grey;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 20px;
}
#content h2 {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 160%;
    margin: 0 0 .5em;
}
#footer {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 20px;
}
```